# Visual Studio 2017 Create method for Multiple button click events on form class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hi all firstly thanks for taking the time to read. I am trying to clean up my code and make it more efficient and want to put some code into one method that will be use for both boutton clicks.

```
private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        y += 1;
        QuestionsFromDb.qid += 1;
        qdb.MultiChoiceFunctionsLight();
        Questions();
        FlagColour();

        //Shows visability for next and previous buttons
        if (y >= 9)
        {
            buttonNext.Visible = false;
            buttonEndQuiz.Visible = true;
        }
        if (y == 1)
        {
            buttonPrevious.Visible = true;
        }

    }

private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        y += 1;
        QuestionsFromDb.qid += 1;
        qdb.MultiChoiceFunctionsLight();
        Questions();
        FlagColour();

        //Shows visability for next and previous buttons
        if (y >= 9)
        {
            buttonNext.Visible = false;
            buttonEndQuiz.Visible = true;
        }
        if (y == 1)
        {
            buttonPrevious.Visible = true;
        }

    }
```

So as you can see i hate repeating my code but with the Button_Click methods im not sure how to set the click to true, false or clicked. This is my idea.

```
private void ButtonClicked()
    {
        if(buttonNext_Click == SOMETHING!)
            {
                if (y >= 9)
                {
                    buttonNext.Visible = false;
                    buttonEndQuiz.Visible = true;
                }
                if (y == 1)
                {
                    buttonPrevious.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        else
           {
                //Shows visability for next and previous buttons
                if (y == 0)
                {
                    buttonPrevious.Visible = false;
                }
                if (y < 10)
                {
                    buttonNext.Visible = true;
                }
        }
    }
```

The code works fine but im am starting to get code OCD i am under the impression that doing it this way will help keep my code more readable and maybe make processing and memory run more effricient. Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Questions like this are better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `im not sure how to set the click to true, false or clicked` - It's not clear what you mean by this.